# Microsoft Graph API File Attachment to List Item

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have simple code to create `sharepoint` List Item and then attach a file using Microsoft Graph.

Steps took:

1) Create Graph Permissions : `SharepointReadWriteFullControl` ( application )
2) Create Graph Permissions : `FileReadWrite` (Application)

Am able to successfully create a `sharepoint` list item ..But unable to attach or get a driveItem from list Item.

I am getting "Code: invalidRequest
Message: Cannot request driveItem for an item that is not in a document library

Inner error"

Answer (score 2):

There are two main templates for lists in SharePoint: document libraries and generic lists. Documents libraries contain ListItems, that are linked to DriveItems. Generic lists only contain ListItems. Based on the error message, I think that you are trying to access the DriveItem for a ListItem in a generic list, which is not possible. You can check the template of the list via Graph Api by getting the list:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/lists/listId

Replace siteId and listId with the IDs from your tenant.
In the result there is a section with information about the list:

```
 "list": {
    "contentTypesEnabled": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "template": "documentLibrary"
}
```

As far as I know, you cannot change the template to a document library, so you may have to create a new document library.